# tvml syntax error : Unexpected token '<'

Tags: tvos, tvml

I am getting Below Error when trying to run apple tv app on simulator:

```
2016-08-27 23:38:46.139 appleTV_Sample[11498:5282178] ITML : SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'...{
line = 1;
sourceURL = "http://localhost:9001//application.js";
}
appController(_:didFailWithError:) invoked with error: Error Domain=TVMLKitErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)"
```

Below is code I used in in my js file:

```
var alertString = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <document>
    <alertTemplate>
      <title>${title}</title>
      <description>${description}</description>
      <button>
        <text>OK</text>
      </button>
    </alertTemplate>
  </document>`
```

Thanks for any pointers to resolve this issue.

Comment: On line 1 you have a syntax error. *SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'...{
line = 1;*

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not the best but at least it allows you to compile the code:

```
var alertString = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>" +
"<document>" +
"<alertTemplate>" +
"<title>${title}</title>" +
"<description>${description}</description>" +
"<button>" +
"<text>OK</text>" +
"</button>" +
"</alertTemplate>" +
"</document>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this line `sourceURL = "http://localhost:9001//application.js"`
You have two slashes